# Question about normal subgroups and conjugacy

Tags: group-theory

Is the following true? I would prefer if a hint can be provided rather than a full solution.

> Let H be a subgroup of the group G. If, for a fixed $g \in G\setminus H$ and a fixed $h_1 \in H\setminus \{e\}$, we have that $g^{-1} h_1 g \in H$ then for all $h \in H$, it is true that $g^{-1}h g \in H$.

Thank you.

Comment: It might help to write this as $h_1g=gh_2$ for some $h_2\in H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you hints you can uncover one at a time.

**Hint 1**

> Consider $G = S_{3} \times C$, where $C$ is a group of order $2$.

**Hint 2**

> Let $H = T \times C$, where $T$ is a fixed subgroup of order $2$ of $S_{3}$.

**Hint 3**

> Let $g$ be an element of order $3$ of $S_{3}$, and $h_{1}$ be a non-identity element of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Here $Z(G)$ denotes the center of the group.

Go searching for a situation where $H$ is not normal and $H\cap Z(G)$ is not trivial.

Then a $h\in H$ and a $g\in G$ can be found such that $g^{-1}hg\notin H$.

Then automatically $g\notin H$ and $g^{-1}h_1g=h_1\in H$ for any $h_1\in H\cap Z(G)$.